# date dependent cell reference

Tags: excel, vba

I was hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction, I'm trying to automate a section of a spread sheet which shows a persons planned hours of work against the hours they actually did. The data is sourced from a worksheet which is broken down into months and departments.

Is there a way to get the reference table on the main dashboard to vlookup/index a certain column dependent on the computers date?

I.E. for May it will look in the planned and actual hours column for may and then in June it will search the June column for the same data.

Normally I would post some code but I'm not even sure where to begin on this one.

Comment: If the months are just in columns, like `jan,Feb,Mar....` then you can do a variable vlookup in vba. Get which month you want and then convert that to a column. So something like `if monthWant = "jan" then column = 1`. Or if the columns never move around. Hard code where the columns are, in a case statement. So something like `Select case monthWanted case is = "jan" monthSelect = 1`. I would start with something like that. Then have the vlookup use the monthselected as a column range

Comment: Cheers Sam I'll give that a go.

Comment: Any problem give me a shout. I have been testing it at the moment have a bit of code. But would need to know how your tables are structured to get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the help in regards to this problem, unfortunatly I could not quite get my head round the suggestions which have been put forward, though I have been able to solve this problem (although it is a messy solution)

```
=IF($F$95="March",VLOOKUP(D97,'Planned Hours'!$A$1:$K$37,2,FALSE),
 IF($F$95="April",VLOOKUP(D97,'Planned Hours'!$A$1:$K$37,3,FALSE),
 IF($F$95="May",VLOOKUP(D97,'Planned Hours'!$A$1:$K$37,4,FALSE),
 IF($F$95="June",VLOOKUP(D97,'Planned Hours'!$A$1:$K$37,5,FALSE),
 IF($F$95="July",VLOOKUP(D97,'Planned Hours'!$A$1:K37,6,FALSE),
 IF($F$95="August",VLOOKUP(D97,'Planned Hours'!$A$1:K37,7,FALSE),
 IF($F$95="September",VLOOKUP(D97,'Planned Hours'!$A$1:K37,8,FALSE),
 IF($F$95="October",VLOOKUP(D97,'Planned Hours'!$A$1:$K$37,9,FALSE),
 IF($F$95="November",VLOOKUP(D97,'Planned Hours'!$A$1:$K$37,10,FALSE),
 IF($F$95="December",VLOOKUP(D97,'Planned Hours'!$A$1:$K$37,11,FALSE)))))))))))
```

But it works. Again thanks to all that lent a hand.

--EDIT--

By the way this is not in VBA in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You mention VLOOKUP in you question.
To use this in VBA use, WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(), but it seems you could avoid VBA altogether if you wanted. Here are some formulas of interest:

If you want to search months by the current date, you can use this kind of vlookup (or MATCH() or HLOOKUP() if these are columns as you indicate)

```
=VLOOKUP(TEXT(TODAY(),"mmmm"),Range,1,FALSE)
```

Use "mmm" if you use 3-letter months

If months are in static column number can be taken from using the MONTH() function.

```
=MONTH(TODAY())
```

"index a certain column dependent on the computers date?"
=TODAY() gets computer's date.
I would tend to use MATCH() to get the months column (in this example I've assumed months are in row 1)

```
=MATCH(TEXT(TODAY(),"mmmm"),1:1,0)
```

You can then use INDIRECT() to match a specific month column and department row (if in a 2D format), or SUMIFS() with INDIRECT() if you want to sum hours.
As in:

```
=INDIRECT("'Sheet'!R" & MATCH("department_name",A:A,0) & "C" & MONTH(TODAY()), FALSE)
```

Comment: You can still use any worksheetfunction inside of VBA so your first point is pretty irrelivant especially since you can do a Vlookup in vba and output the results to a cell

Comment: Yes I meant you can use VLOOKUP by VBA using Worksheetfunction, but it is unnecessary. I have reworded.